# Trying to setup Master Slave setup of Jmeter in Cloud, Receiving "java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect"

Tags: jmeter, cloud, master-slave, distributed-testing

I'm Trying to setup Master Slave setup of Jmeter in Cloud.

Things I have done the setup in CLOUD for Master and Slave

- I have created `rmi.keystore.jks` file in Master and copied the same to Slave machine.
- I have installed the same versions of Java and Jmeter in both the Machines
- I have added IP address of Slave machine in `jmeter.properties` file of Master

Please help me why I'm facing connection timed out error when trying to execute jmeter script in Cloud machine. Receiving:

> Connection refused to host: 10.XXX.XX.XXX; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Silly question - Do you start jmeter on slave?

Comment: Yes I did start the Jmeter server.bat in slave machine.. Not a silly question I guess..

Answer (score 1):

If this is really in CLOUD then:

1. My expectation is that you need to use **external** IP addresses as I can only see [Class B network-type address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network) which most probably cannot be connected from the outer world
2. You need to ensure that the following ports are open in the CLOUD (whatever you mean by this term) and in operating system firewalls/security groups:

   - `1099` (or whatever port you define as the `server_port`)
   - the port you define as the `server.rmi.localport`
   - the port(s) you define as the `client.rmi.localport`

More information:

- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/)

Comment: Where can I check my server port and Can you please tell me how to change?

Comment: These ports are defined in `jmeter.properties` file in `jmeter/bin/` I check mine, I set `server.rmi.port` too (not sure if necessary).